# create windows phone project in vs 2012,but it show 'start' quick menu not the 'device'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Now I use vs 2012 to develop windows phone app, when I create a windows phone project, It can create successfully,but It show 'start' like:

[image]

and it should be like:

[image]

what's the problem?

Comment: What does the down arrow show?

Comment: @Stefan just the "start", no others.

Comment: Did you create a windows store app by mistake?

Comment: @Andy, no..previous wp project just show "start", two!

Comment: Did you check this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629255.aspx)[Link]..

Comment: Is that an express version? Or are you running multiple projects in the same solution?